# Dropping PostgreSQL partition is blocked as long as a client is reading data from any partition

Tags: postgresql, partitioning, blocking, drop-table

I have a simple partitioned table in PostgreSQL 14, like this:

```
create table entity
(
    dataset_id integer not null references dataset (id),
    ...
) partition by list (dataset_id);

create table entity_1
(
    like entity including constraints including defaults,
    constraint entity_1_pkey primary key (entity_id),
);

alter table entity attach partition entity_1 for values in (1);
```

The reason for creating a partition a partition "detached" first and then attaching it in a separate statement is to avoid taking an exclusive lock on the parent table (`entity`), which would block creating a partition as long as a client was reading from any other partition. This was the solution suggested by **Laurenz Albe** in https://stackoverflow.com/a/67016755/1536933 and it works great for creating partitions.

Unfortunately, I have the same problem when *dropping* partitions: as long as a client is reading data from any partition I cannot drop any other partition: not only is `drop table entity_1` blocked, but even `alter table entity detach partition entity_1 concurrently` is blocked! I cannot see any relevant lock in `pg_locks` for the "detach concurrently" statement (nothing with `granted=false`), but the pgAdmin dashboard shows `Wait event:  Lock: virtualxid` and `Blocking PIDs: (pid of the reading process)`

What can I do to drop partitions while data is being read from other partitions? Surely this should be possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ALTER TABLE ... DETACH PARTITION CONCURRENTLY` is the best tool you have. Yes, it will wait until all transactions that read the table are done, but that shouldn't be a problem, because concurrent reads are not blocked at any time. Simply wait until the reading transactions are done (all transactions must end some day), and you are good.

Note that you need not wait until there is no active transaction on the table: you only have to wait until all transactions *that were active when you started `ALTER TABLE`* are finished.

Comment: Ah yes, that last bit is key, thanks! I tested it and you're right - the `ALTER TABLE` finishes after the original read finishes, even if I start a new read transaction. I'll use that then, though it unfortunately refuses to run in a procedure (fails with "ERROR:  ALTER TABLE ... DETACH CONCURRENTLY cannot be executed from a function") so my client application will have to run a separate command for it, which is annoying.

Comment: Yes, it cannot run inside a transaction, because it is implemented as two separate transactions. Perhaps annoying, but workable.

Comment: No transaction is fine, but is there any way to run it as part of a procedure (not function, as the error says)? It does not start a transaction. I even tried adding a "commit;" immediately before to ensure there is no transaction, but still got the same error.

Comment: Right, because you also have a surrounding transaction in a procedure. There is no way to avoid that.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe - is the `DETACH PARTITION CONCURRENTLY` clever enough to know that no transactions are accessing the partition in question - which would normally be the reason for dropping the partition anyway - no longer of use?